# Systemd stop unit before another unit

Tags: systemd

I've created a service for manage some backups of my virtual machines.

This service should execute a script when the host is shutting down, and another script when the host start again.

My service file have this:

```
[Unit]
Description=...
After=libvirtd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/scripts/check.sh
ExecStop=/scripts/backup.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, my check.sh script Works fine, but my script backup.sh when I reboot or shut down my host, it doesn't work, because my service and libvirtd.service stops at the same time.

How can I make my service stops before libvirtd.service?

**edit:**

My service will only works if the guest machines are running, so libvirt or something (not libvirt-guests, because I disabled it) is shutting off them.

Comment: According to systemd.unit [manpage][1]:

"Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied. i.e. if a unit is configured with After= on another unit, the former is stopped before the latter if both are shut down."

When you are saying it's failing, what do you mean?

  [1]: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: I added new info. I think if the guest machines don't shut off, my service might work.

Comment: Why did you disable the `libvirt-guests.service`? If it's disabled, I'm not sure anything will cleanly shutdown the VM's before the host is rebooted/shutdown. Did you try to use `After=libvirt-guests.service` instead?

Comment: I disabled it for testing, but the guest machines still shutting down before my service stop. Maybe, is something more shutting down the guest machines.